# Array remove duplicates based on index / preserve first occurance

Tags: php, performance, algorithm, php-5.3

I have wrote a simple algorithm to only store the first occurrence of a name in my array of artists. I am not concerned with the artist ID. The algorithm works fine but I am worried about performance. Does anybody see a simpler way to write this that would also improve performance if the $performers array was say 200 artists?

```
$performers = array(
   array('id' => '12','name' => 'Grouplove'),
   array('id' => '24','name' => 'Grouplove'),
   array('id' => '43','name' => 'Coldplay')
);

$tmp = array();
foreach($performers as $performer)
{
   $count = 0;
   foreach($tmp as $test)
   {
      if($performer['name'] == $test['name'])
      {
         $count++;
      }
   }
   if(!$count)
   {
      $tmp[] = $performer;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not concerned with the artist ID then:

```
$tmp = array_unique(array_map(function($value) {
                return $value["name"];
            }, $performers));
```

the result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Grouplove
    [2] => Coldplay
)
```

Otherwise:

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($performers as $performer) {
    if(!in_array($performer["name"], array_map(function($value) {
                return $value["name"];
            }, $tmp))) {
        $tmp[] = $performer;
    }
}
```

the result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => Grouplove
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 43
            [name] => Coldplay
        )

)
```

Comment: I am concerned with the ID only on the end result. So you second option looks better than mine

Answer (score 3):

When adding them to `$tmp` array you can specify the key to be the name of the artist. Then you can just check if `isset($tmp[$performer['name']])` is true and skip it if it already exists. That way you will avoid the inner loop. After populating the new `$tmp` array if the keys are the problem you can get only values with `array_values($tmp)`.

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($performers as $performer) {
  if(!isset($tmp[$performer['name']]){
    $tmp[$performer['name']] = $performer;
  }
}
```

you will get something like:

```
array(
    'Grouplove' => array(
            'id' => '12',
            'name' => 'Grouplove',
     ),
    'Coldplay'  =>array(
            'id' => '43',
            'name' => 'Coldplay'
     )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use the built-in function [array unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) since you aren't concerned about the artist ID?

Comment: concerned with it in the end result, but not on the initial sort